# Availability of Apache Geode releases roadmap

Tags: geode

Could you please tell me whether do you have releases roadmap? We are waiting for 1.14 - do you have any planned date for this release?

Thanks,
Vadim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an up to date website containing this information, other than the [Release Schedule](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Release+Schedule) (totally outdated) or [Shipping patch Releases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Shipping+patch+releases) (no schedule whatsoever) within the wiki.
That said, the best option at the moment would be to monitor (or directly ask) within the [Users](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.apache.geode.user%20order%3Adate-backward) or [Devs](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.apache.geode.dev%20order%3Adate-backward) mailing lists (you can subscribe [here](https://geode.apache.org/community/))